# how to filter a list through a dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter a list by a property that is set by a dropdown:

```
<select ng-model="filterItem" ng-options="item.name for item in filterOptions.stores">
</select>
```

This is the the data for the dropdown:

```
$scope.filterOptions = {
    stores: [
      {id : 2, name : 'Show All', rating: 6 },
            {id : 3, name : 'Rating 5', rating: 5 },
      {id : 4, name : 'Rating 4', rating: 4 },
      {id : 5, name : 'Rating 3', rating: 3 },
      {id : 6, name : 'Rating 2', rating: 2 },
      {id : 7, name : 'Rating 1', rating: 1 } 
    ]
  };
```

The filter is actually not working properly through the rating property: it returns more that just the one selected property:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data | filter:filterItem.rating" >
        Name: {{item.name}} Price: {{item.price}} Rating: {{item.rating}}
</li>
```

How can I fix the filter here?
This is a plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/vAebEb?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are setting filterItem.rating as the filter, so you're setting a string as the filter. From docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> The string is used for matching against the contents of the array. All
>   strings or objects with string properties in array that match this
>   string will be returned. This also applies to nested object
>   properties. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with
>   !.

What this is doing is matching ANY property in your array with the value filterItem.rating; so product's with the number in their product name are also being matched.

Since you want the filter to ONLY apply to the rating property, you want to set an object like this:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{rating:filterItem.rating}" >
```

That will now filter properly, but Show All doesn't work properly since filterItem.rating is undefined when it's show all. Since we don't want the filter to apply when Show All is selected, you can check for the filterItem.rating property first:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data | filter:filterItem.rating && {rating:filterItem.rating}" >
```

I've updated your Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/q5Ns8c6HN1eIGZANlI4s?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of changes:

1. In your $scope.filterOptions.stores object: Remove the rating for Show All option like:

`{id : 2, name : 'Show All'},`

2. In your html where you are using filter:

`<li data-ng-repeat="item in data | filter:filterItem.rating && {rating:filterItem.rating}">`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed. The approach is same.

Comment: then what is the reason behind repeating answer again?

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. It doesn't work for the Show All functionality and I did not see the other answer given by "mofojed".
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes dude..but mofojed answered that thing in comment and he has also explained the thing by adding answer